# Finding it very hard to find xml examples for native script. Is there a bootsnip for native script?

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to create a bottom bar in native script. My first attempt is below with very rudimentary idea. I am thinking of using font awesome then put the word below the icon. My question is are there any sample xml for this or website that has xml like bootsnip for bootstrap and whether hthe code below is a good way to accomplish the goal bottom navigation bar depicted in the picture.

[image]

```
 <DockLayout stretchLastChild="true">
        <StackLayout dock="bottom" verticalAlignment="bottom" stretch="fill">
            <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" horizontalAlignment="center">
                <Label text="Home" dock="left" backgroundColor="red"></Label>
                <Label text="Medications" dock="left" backgroundColor="green"></Label>
                <Label text="Medication Detail" dock="left" backgroundColor="blue"></Label>
                <Label text="Whatever" backgroundColor="yellow"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </DockLayout>
```

Comment: Http://nativescriptsnacks.com has some samples. I think you want the tabview component in NativeScript for that UI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [NativeScript Tab View Sample code](http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-samples/ui/tab-view)

**OR**

try this:
You may replace the [ScrollView](http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-samples/ui/scroll-view) with you [ListView](http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-samples/ui/listview)

```xml
<GridLayout rows="*, auto, auto">
    <ScrollView row="0">
        <StackLayout row="0" backgroundColor="#eeeeee">
            <Label text="Hello world" textWrap="true"></Label>
            <Label text="Hello world" textWrap="true"></Label>
            <Label text="Hello world" textWrap="true"></Label>
            <Label text="Hello world" textWrap="true"></Label>
            <Label text="Hello world" textWrap="true"></Label>
            <Label text="Hello world" textWrap="true"></Label>
            <Label text="Hello world" textWrap="true"></Label>
            <Label text="Hello world" textWrap="true"></Label>
            <Label text="Hello world" textWrap="true"></Label>
            <Label text="Hello world" textWrap="true"></Label>
            <Label text="Hello world" textWrap="true"></Label>
            <Label text="Hello world" textWrap="true"></Label>
            <Label text="Hello world" textWrap="true"></Label>
            <Label text="Hello world" textWrap="true"></Label>
            <Label text="Hello world" textWrap="true"></Label>
            <Label text="Hello world" textWrap="true"></Label>
            <Label text="Hello world" textWrap="true"></Label>
            <Label text="Hello world" textWrap="true"></Label>
            <Label text="Hello world" textWrap="true"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <StackLayout height="2" backgroundColor="#777" row="1"></StackLayout>
    <GridLayout class="foot" columns="*,*,*,*" row="2">
        <Label col="0" text="" textWrap="true"></Label>
        <Label col="1" text="" textWrap="true"></Label>
        <Label col="2" text="" textWrap="true"></Label>
        <Label col="3" text="" textWrap="true"></Label>
    </GridLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

```css
   .foot {
        background-color: #ccc;
    }

    .foot label {
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding: 10;
        font-size: 20;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for sharing your knowledge. I miss the fact native script site had examples.